# Some problems in EDPs course

Tags: partial-differential-equations

1. Built a function f(x) $\in$  $C^2((0,1))$ such that

$f(x)=x , \ \forall x \in (0,\frac{2}{5}) \cup (\frac{4}{5} , 1) \ \ \ \exists x_0 \in (\frac{2}{5} , \frac{4}{5}) s.t. f(x_0) \neq x_0$

2. Find the general solution of $u_{xx} +y u_x =0$. You have to find all $u \in C^2 (\mathbb{R^2})$ that sadisfies the equation.

I have some problems to do this exercices. Help me, pls

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I wanted to know how to do this exercices because I don't know how to approch with ..